# How to Avoid dynamic query with multiple IF statements within IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a following situation: how to write the code in efficient way.

```
DECLARE @sql   VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @where VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

IF @is_clean_label = 1
   SET @where = @where+ N'Clean Label,'

IF @Is_KeyInterview = 1
   SET @where = @where+N'Key Interview,'

IF @Is_SpecialReport = 1
   SET @where = @where+N'Special Report,'

SET @sql = N' SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE  Name in ('+@where+')'

EXEC (@sql)
```

If the above statement throws an error if no param is added

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Need to return all values if no condition applies.

Is it possible to avoid dynamic SQL?

Comment: your @where would contain a preceding `,`; write some logic to remove that initial comma before adding to sql

Comment: You should move , after the string and should not be part of the values. Use ' three times to enclose the value in string. Example it shouldn't be where + N',Clean Label'. It should be where + '''Clean Label''' + ','. Also as others have said remove any , in the beggining or end from where string. Use CHARINDEX to find , and SUBSTRING to cut the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do almost whatever you want with case statements in the where clause which allows you to essentially move your IF then logic into the where clause directly.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    TableName
WHERE
    (CASE
       WHEN @is_clean_label = 1 AND Name = 'Clean Label' THEN 1
       ELSE 0
    END) = 1
    OR
    (CASE
       WHEN @Is_KeyInterview = 1 AND Name = 'Key Interview' THEN 1
       ELSE 0
    END) = 1
    OR
    (CASE
       WHEN @Is_SpecialReport = 1 AND Name = 'Special Report' THEN 1
       ELSE 0
    END) = 1
    OR
    (CASE
       WHEN (COALESCE(@Is_SpecialReport,0) + COALESCE(@Is_KeyInterview,0) + COALESCE(@Is_SpecialReport,0))  = 0 THEN 1
       ELSE 0
    END) = 1
```

I too would often use the table route that John wrote but I think it is important to show this technique as it is useful many times.  I also agree with a few of the other comments stay away from dynamic sql when it is not truly needed!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps no need to go Dynamic  **UPDATED to Include ALL of no Selection**

```
Declare @InList Table (KeyVal varchar(50),Include int)

Insert Into @InList 
values ('Clean Label', @is_clean_label),
       ('Key Interview', @Is_KeyInterview),
       ('Special Report', @Is_SpecialReport)

SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE Name IN (SELECT KeyVal 
               FROM @InList 
               WHERE Include = (SELECT MAX(sign(Include)) FROM @InList))
```

Comment: I need to return all values if no condition applied !

Comment: @Ragul  You may want to add that additional requirement to your original question.

Comment: @Ragul Fair enough, but that not stated in your requirements.  Not sure it was worthy of an "!"

Comment: @Ragul Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

First, good job reaching out trying to find a non dynamic sql way.

The "trick" below is to consider the count of the look up table.

IMHO, ignore all "try this" that include dynamic sql answers.  if the problem can be solved without dynamic sql, it should be IMHO.  You can read about some of the issues here : http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/don-t-fear-dynamic-sql  Even if you use it, there are decent ways and idiotic ways to use it.

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableOne') IS NOT NULL
    begin
            drop table #TableOne
    end


    CREATE TABLE #TableOne
    ( 
    SurrogateKeyIDENTITY int not null IDENTITY (1,1) , 
    MyLabel varchar(16)
    )

    Insert into #TableOne ( MyLabel ) select 'Clean Label' UNION ALL select 'Clean Label' UNION ALL select 'Key Interview' UNION ALL select 'Key Interview' UNION ALL select  'Special Report' UNION ALL select  'Special Report' UNION ALL select 'NotAMatch' UNION ALL select  'NotAMatch'


Declare @LookupMatchTable Table (KeyVal varchar(50))
if(1=1) /* use your bool flags here */
begin
    Insert Into @LookupMatchTable (KeyVal) Select 'Clean Label'
end
if(1=1) /* use your bool flags here */
begin
    Insert Into @LookupMatchTable (KeyVal) Select 'Key Interview'
end
if(1=1) /* use your bool flags here */
begin
    Insert Into @LookupMatchTable (KeyVal) Select 'Special Report'
end

declare @LookupMatchTableCount int 
select @LookupMatchTableCount = (select count(*) from @LookupMatchTable)


SELECT * FROM #TableOne t1 WHERE ( @LookupMatchTableCount = 0 OR EXISTS (Select KeyVal  from @LookupMatchTable lmt where lmt.KeyVal = t1.MyLabel ) )

/* now show if there are no entries in the look up table, everything comes back */
delete from @LookupMatchTable
select @LookupMatchTableCount = (select count(*) from @LookupMatchTable)
SELECT * FROM #TableOne t1 WHERE ( @LookupMatchTableCount = 0 OR EXISTS (Select KeyVal  from @LookupMatchTable lmt where lmt.KeyVal = t1.MyLabel ) )


/* now show that if there is something in the lookup table that doesn't match the "real" table......no rows returned */
delete from @LookupMatchTable
    Insert Into @LookupMatchTable (KeyVal) Select 'No Match Whatsoever'
select @LookupMatchTableCount = (select count(*) from @LookupMatchTable)
SELECT * FROM #TableOne t1 WHERE ( @LookupMatchTableCount = 0 OR EXISTS (Select KeyVal  from @LookupMatchTable lmt where lmt.KeyVal = t1.MyLabel ) )




    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableOne') IS NOT NULL
    begin
            drop table #TableOne
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `@where` variable would contain a preceding `comma` due to the concatenation logic you have.

Remove the first `comma` and you should be good to go!!

```
SET @where = STUFF(@where, 1, 1, '')
SET @sql = N' SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE  Name in ('+@where+')'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your script.

First, the leading comma in your `in` list.

Second, you aren't handling when no flags are set

And Third, you are not adding single quotes to your `in` list either:

```
DECLARE @sql   NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @where NVARCHAR(MAX)

IF  @is_clean_label = 1
SET @where = isnull(@where + ',','')+ N'''Clean Label'''

IF  @Is_KeyInterview = 1
SET @where = isnull(@where + ',','')+ N'''Key Interview'''

IF  @Is_SpecialReport = 1
SET @where = isnull(@where + ',','')+ N'''Special Report'''

SET @sql = N' SELECT * FROM TABLE'
            + case when @where <> ''
                    then ' WHERE  Name in ('+@where+')'
                    else ''
                    end
EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just forgot dynamic SQL. go with below query and let me know if any   changes requried.

```
select * from TABLE 
where (Name ='Clean Label' or @is_clean_label=0) 
and ((Name ='Key Interview' or @Is_KeyInterview=0))
and ((Name ='Special Report' or @Is_SpecialReport=0))
```